# drawing overlapping circles in corona

Tags: coronasdk

How to draw a circle overlapping another circle in the moved phase of touch event,such that no gap is left out between the circles.The circles must be tightly packed to one another,so that even when user moves his hand on the screen faster or lightly,no gap must be present between the circles.

Answer (score 0):

Just two circles?  Or many circles?  If just two, then detecting if they overlap is simply verifying that their centers are not closer than the sum of their radii.  For example, if Circle1's raduis is 10 pixels, and Circle2's radius is 25 pixels, then they overlap if the center of Circle1 is less than 35 pixels from the center of Circle2.

So if you do your calculations in the "moved" phase and find that they're too close, you have to adjust the position of one of them.  How you go about that will depend on the specifics of your application.  You could:

- Keep the y coordinate of the moving circle the same, and calculate the necessary x coordinate to maintain the required distance.
- Same as above but swap x and y.
- As above, but move the "unmoving" circle away from the "moving" circle.
- Some other calculation that makes sense for your application.

NOTE: You should accept some of the answers you've been given.